# Creating cosmos collection doesn't give partition key or throughput options on more than 1 collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When I create new collection from azure portal it only gives me the option to choose partition key and throughput if it's the first collection I make in that database.  When I add a second collection, it's just showing me option to enter collection id and unique key, but no option to set partition key or throughput on that collection.  It just creates the second table with no partition key or throughput.  Why is this happening, how do I set the omsorderid and throughput on additional collections in the database?

Comment: I can see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eklgF.png. Can you please edit your question and include a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: apparently the partition key is set at the database level?  if i try to make a new collection on an existing database it doesn't let me choose partition key for the collection

Comment: yet if i make the new collection under the existing database then that new collection just doesn't have a partition key at all...

Comment: It really is gone, very weird... https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG5Ty.png - you will need to create the collections via API for the time being https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cli-samples

Comment: You haven't provided any screenshots, so I'm *guessing* it's similar to what @AlexAIT posted. I'd contact support. I can't reproduce this, whether with a long-existing Cosmos DB account or a just-created account. And I've tried with both database-provisioned throughput and collection-specific throughput. It all works fine for me.